# Query to check if we have any row which start with input String

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

lets say have column with values

**"Html", "Java", "JQuery", "Sqlite"**

and if user enters

> "Java is my favorite programming language"

then result should be

> 1 row selected with value "Java"

because entered sentence starts with "Java"

but if user enters

> "My application database is in Sqlite"

then query should return empty.

> 0 row selected

because entered sentence does not start with "Sqlite".

I am trying following query:

```
SELECT * FROM demo where 'Java' like demo.name; // work
```

but if enter long text then it fails

```
SELECT * FROM demo where 'Java is my favorite programming language' like demo.name; // Fails
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE yourText LIKE demo.name || '%' ;
```

Comment: You should replace `+` with `||` to concatenate strings.

Comment: @Eritrean thank you I thought + will concatenate the strings

Answer (score 2):

Just put the column name on the left side of the `like` operator, and concatenate a wildcard at the right side of your string keywork:

```
select * from demo where name like 'Java%' ; -- or like 'Sqlite%' etc
```

You can make it more generic like:

```
select * from demo where name like ? || %' ;
```

where `?` is a bind parameter that represents the value provided by the user (you may also concatenate with  the wildcard in your application before passing the parameter).

Comment: I cant control what user is going to enter. how would I know if user have entered Java

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate your column with a wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM demo where 'Java is my favorite programming language' like demo.name || '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your query like this

```
Select * from SearchPojo where name GLOB '*' || :namestring|| '*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the problem but ...

You can query these values (Html, Java, JQuery, Sqlite) put them in a collection, like List, then grab user's input and check it:

```
List<String> values ... // Html, Java, JQuery, Sqlite

for (String value : values) {
   if (userInput.contains(value) {
      // print
      System.out.println("1 row selected with value \"Java\");
   }
}
```

It supports cases where user type more then one option.